# Colums to rows based on unique ID

Tags: r, transpose

My data is currently formatted as such:

```
    ID  PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4
    5   8970    864     
    6   2800    2812    2801    284
```

What I would like is a separate row for each data point, linked to the unique ID so that:

```
    ID  PC
    5   8970
    5   864
    6   2800
    6   2812
    6   2801
    6   284
```

I realise this is a very basic question, but in looking for similar questions I can only find ways to do this the other way around!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `reshape` like below

```
dfout <- setNames(reshape(df,
                          direction = "long",
                          idvar = "ID",
                          varying = list(grep("^PC",names(df))))[-2],
                  c("ID","PC"))

dfout <- `row.names<-`(subset(dfout[order(dfout$ID),],!is.na(PC)),NULL)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  ID   PC
1  5 8970
2  5  864
3  6 2800
4  6 2812
5  6 2801
6  6  284
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 5:6, PC1 = c(8970L, 2800L), PC2 = c(864L, 
2812L), PC3 = c(NA, 2801L), PC4 = c(NA, 284L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(5,6), 
  PC1 = c(8970, 2800), 
  PC2 = c(864, 2812), 
  PC3 = c(NA, 2801), 
  PC4 = c(NA, 284)
)



df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "PC_code", values_to = "value") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-PC_code)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this returns an error: 
Error: Can't select within an unnamed vector.

Let me specify that I have this all in a data frame, loaded from a CSV

Comment: Weird, I've edited my comment to reproduce your dataframe.  My code works with that.  I've also added a filter to get rid of NA values which I assume you don't want in your output.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to fill blanks with `NA's` you can do this easy by:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate_all(na_if,"")
```

My naive solution, but clear:

```
library(reshape)
Input = (
  'ID  PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4
5   8970    864     NA     NA    
6   2800    2812    2801    284')
df = read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T)
df
res <- melt(df,id='ID')
res$variable <- NULL
res <- res[complete.cases(res),]
res <- res[order(res$ID),]
colnames(res)[2] <- 'PC'
res
  ID   PC
1  5 8970
3  5  864
2  6 2800
4  6 2812
6  6 2801
8  6  284
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think this only works for the small part of the data that I gave as an example? I have ID 1-195 and PC 1-30, while the input here seems very limited? Let me specify that I have this all in a data frame, loaded from a CSV

Comment: So it isn't working on you whole dataset loaded from csv? Actually it should, however you can provide more rows and columns.